# meaning of "subdued"

Tags: word-meaning

"Subdue" means to control a group of people. So, I expected that "subdued" to mean "people/things under control". So, I expected to use it like "subdued people/nations/groups/countries/etc.". However, it apparently means something else.

So, what other terms I can use for my purpose above, "groups or people under sovereignty or control (of a historical Empire)"?

Answer (score 2):

*Subdue* does have several uses, but really only one meaning - to bring something under control.

If you were to describe a colour as "subdued" it means that it is muted, not too loud - as if controlled.

Similarly if a person is described as "subdued" they may be sullen, as if controlled by their emotions.

If you want to use it to describe groups or people under sovereignty or control, don't be put off by the other uses - context will make the meaning clear.

However, subdued in this sense also describes that *action* of bringing people or a country under control, or subjection. Using the word subdued implies that there may have been some military act such as an invasion. If you simply want to state that a group or nation is under the control of another without getting into the history of how that came about, you may want to choose a word other than *subdued*.

Synonyms of **subdued** in the sense of a military takeover include:

- conquered
- overpowered
- suppressed

As you can see, these mostly have negative connotations.

To simply show sovereignty you could use:

- ruled
- governed
- controlled

Answer (score 1):

Well, *subdue* is a verb and the general usage of this verb is *subdue something.* And, it is not always the case of people or group. You can subdue your evil part as well!

There could be many words to describe groups/people under some control. Now, if the *control* is of some fascist or dictator, the only word that comes to my mind is *slave.*

[Collins says:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slave)

> You can describe someone as a slave when they are **completely under the control** of another person or of a powerful influence.

Though, let others pour in with their opinions.

Comment: Thanks, It seems I must say that I mean under the control of a historical Empire....

Comment: No, you cannot decide *historical empire* by just putting the word 'under control.' Even today, some dictator can control the entire population of his country! We *do* have a couple of them today...don't we! There, *history* has nothing to do! So, in whatever case, the people are under control, basically slaves! Because the fascist can use them as he wants!

Answer (score 0):

Subdued can be either enforced or voluntary.

"The army subdued the citizens after the invasion, imposing curfews & arresting people for the slightest misdemeanour."

"If you consider the effusive way people from the Mediterranean greet each other, then look to the English, you will see they are far more subdued."

Additionally colours can be subdued, ie not very bright.
Subdued sounds are not very loud.